# UWP CalendarView changes year after resize

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

Im implementing `CalendarView` in my app, and after resizing window, actually after resizing window `Height`, the `year` in `CalendarView` changes too!
How to prevent this? [App Window with Calendar View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvgY8.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4c2f0b04-8395-4ca7-8fca-cd864075750c/uwpxamlcbug-reportcalendarview-shows-random-dates-when-resizing-the-window?forum=wpdevelop) answer on MSDN, it's a known issue. You can temporarily fix it by using fixed `Height` and `Width` values.